# Find a pattern within' long string

Tags: php, regex

I have a question with some patterns I'm trying to do... this is the code I have:

```
$test = 'this is a simply test';

preg_match_all("/^this is a [a-zA-Z] test$/", $test, $op_string);

print_r($op_string);
```

I've been trying for this guys, but this doesn't works properly. This should output: `simply`

The pattern must contains same as `$test` (the string I mean... it can't contain only [a-zA-Z] because we'll need to find it more exactly as possible).

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this:**

```
$re = "/^this is a ([a-zA-Z\\s]+) test$/m";
$str = "this is a simply test";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);  // here you get match word or word set
```

[**live demo**](https://regex101.com/r/gO9jE0/1)

**output:**

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'simply' (length=6)
```

Comment: `([a-zA-Z\\s]+)` is actually wrong regex for matching `simply`

Comment: your comment true. but i think may be word set (more than one word). so, i have written  this  pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Use quantifier `+` to match 1 or more letters:

```
$test = 'this is a simply test';
preg_match_all('/^this is a [a-zA-Z]+ test$/', $test, $op_string);
```

You're using `[a-zA-Z]` which will only match a **single letter**.

Comment: Hello @anubhava, it returns this: 
`Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => this is a simply test ) )` this should return an array with "simply"... am I right? Thanks!

Comment: If you just want `simply` in a captured group then use: `preg_match_all('/^this is a ([a-zA-Z]+) test$/', $test, $op_string);` then use `$op_string[1]`

Comment: Without using captured group you can use lookaheads like this: `preg_match_all('/(?<=^this is a )[a-zA-Z]+(?= test$)/', $test, $op_string);`